# How to change CPU frequency via Java code (Or ADB commands via Java code)?

Tags: android, adb, cpu, root, superuser

I was able to successfully execute these commands via ADB and was able to change CPU frequency.

```
adb root
adb shell
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu
echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo 1152000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 1152000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

I wanna execute these via Java code, so I tried this approach:

```java
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("adb shell" + "\n");
os.flush();
```

but it gives exception on first line. 
`java.io.Exception: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working directory: null Environment: null`

I'm executing these commands in system app, with custom ROM, `android 5.0`

Can you tell me how to execute these commands in java code? 
Or do I need to create a bash file to execute these commands?

Comment: Just throwing an idea out... if this is a system app, is it possible just to open each of the files in turn and write the required line to them from Java?

Comment: It's giving permission denied.

Comment: I tried this: `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq");`
            `writer.write("1152000");`
           `writer.close();`

Comment: If it's possible (I'm not an Android expert), you probably need some high-level Android permission to write to such files. From what I've seen, a normal app cannot be given such permission, but it's _possible_ a "system" app can.

Comment: When you say java code, is it the android app code or the dev (windows/mac/ubuntu) box code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `adb shell` on the device ...

```
try {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes("echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor\n");
    os.writeBytes("echo 1152000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq\n");
    os.writeBytes("echo 1152000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");

    os.flush();
    os.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Read questions details before answering... I already mentioned "su" not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions w.r.t. you question:

1. I believe that running su may not be possible in user/production env. For the development environment does giving path of su command helps you can try (if su is a binary present on target at path /bin/ or a soft link to some kind of toolbox).

   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/su");
2. Since your question mentions that you are making a priv-app, so assuming that you have privilege to modify the system initialization script(init.rc) i am writing this suggestion.

The way I can see this possible in user env on Android 5.0, with some past experience on similar kind of requirement was  :-

1. from Java code set a property.
2. on this property trigger the requisite actions from init script.
3. Since init script has all the access, so it should be possible.

So,

in the init.rc script you can have  :-

on property:persist.write.cpu=writecpu

write /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor userspace

write /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq 1152000

write /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq 1152000

from the Java code:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setprop persist.write.cpu writecpu");
    p.destroy();
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately i do not have setup of 5.0 to confirm but (1) or (2) may give you some help to progress.

Thanks.